# execution fails for a hid device application

Tags: c, linux, hid

I am very new to programming USB devices, so please accept my apologies if the question is dumb.

I have a simple usb device (It is a filterwheel device) that I want to use in an embedded application. The supplier has provided me with a c source code that works based on hidapi. I am trying to run a simple application on a linux pc first. I can successfully build the project, but as I run the project, it terminates at enumeration step with et value -1.

The device is connected to my computer. I am quite lost on what I should do to make it identify the device.Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

I do not know what information I can add here, the application looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    hsfw_wheel_info *devs, *cur_dev;
    devs = enumerate_wheels();
    cur_dev = devs;
    while (cur_dev) {
        printf("Device Found - type: %04hx %04hx serial_number: %ls\n",cur_dev->vendor_id, cur_dev->product_id, cur_dev->serial_number);

        cur_dev = cur_dev->next;
    }
```

The enumerate_wheels is a function that uses hid_enumerate.

Thank you

Comment: with a `-1` value, it would seem that the call to `enumerate_wheels()` isn't working. Can you step thru that code in a debugger? (Don't know anything about hid_usb, this is just a general observation). Good luck!

Comment: And I would expect that `devs` would be some data structure can that can hold a list. OR as this is `c-lang`. more likely you need a pointer to an array of pointers, maybe declared as `**devs`? Really guessing here, but as you've had no other feedback, hoping this might give you something new to poke at ;-) . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @shellter. I changed from hid.c that uses libusb to the one for native linux and I got passed the enumeration step. Now it fails at opening the device (/dev/hidraw0). The open(path,0_RDWR) call does not open the device.

I assume it is a permission problem? I read several posts that I should fix it by setuid, how should I change this permission for a program that should communicate with a hid device at some point? Is there an environment variable that I can set?

Thank you so much.